How to update a property based on Object.location?
I want to update the co property value when the object property's location changes.
Can I use bpy.msgbus and how to use it?
class XX_PG_point(PropertyGroup):

    object: PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)

    co: FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Coordinates",
        subtype="XYZ",
        size=3,
    )


class XX_PG_location(PropertyGroup):

    points: CollectionProperty(type=XX_PG_point)
    active_point_index: IntProperty(name="Active Point Index")


bpy.msgbus wont work for this.  see here

The following updates do not trigger message bus notifications:

Moving objects in the 3D Viewport.

Changes performed by the animation system.


But you can use a bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post
Every time the depsgraph updates, depsgraph_update_handler will run:
def depsgraph_update_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    for update in depsgraph.updates:
        if isinstance(update.id, Object):
            obj = update.id
            scene.your_props.co = obj.location.x


def register():
   Scene.your_props = PointerProperty(type=your_props)
   bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(depsgraph_update_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(depsgraph_update_handler)
    del Scene.your_props

If you have a larger, multi-file addon, put this in your __init__.py file.
